# Plotting a series using gnuplot (Maclaurin series)

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a quick way to plot the Maclaurin/Taylor series using Gnuplot. For eg:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series
I'm trying to plot each term of the series NOT the series f(x) vs x.
So, for sin(x) I'd like to plot on the x-axis, x, -x^3/3!, x^5/5! etc and the sum itself all on one axis without having to type each term in the sequence manually.

Comment: I don't want to plot each term manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [plot functions](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-functions/) in gnuplot. In this case, you would have to define your series, for example:

```
gnuplot> a0 = 1
gnuplot> a1 = 0.5
gnuplot> a2 = 0.1
gnuplot> f(x) = a0 + a1*x**2 + a2*x**3
gnuplot> plot f(x)
```

This will give you:

[image: plot series]

**Edit**

Based on the comment to this answer, I'm proposing this (which should work for **gnuplot 4.4** and higher):

First, define your factorial:

```
gnuplot> fac(n) = (n==0) ? 1 : n * fac(n-1)
```

Second, iterate over as many terms as you like (in this case `10`). We're only interested in the uneven exponents, hence the upper bound is `20`. Furthermore, every other "term" has to be multiplied by `-1`, thus two commands, and an increment of `4`:

```
plot for [a=3:21:4] -1*x**a/fac(a), for [a=1:21:4] x**a/fac(a)
```

This will give you a plot like this:

[image: plot terms]

Comment: No! I want to plot each term of the series on one axis (x-axis). The Taylor's series has 'x' and 'a' right. So I wanted to mark a point x = pi/2 and then plot x, -x^3/3!, +x^5/5! etc and then change to x=pi/3 etc to see how the magnitude of each term varied

Comment: @paleywiener : isn't that the same as plotting `f(x) = x`, `g(x) = -x^3/3!` and so forth?

Comment: Actually, FWIW, it should probably work with gnuplot4.3 and higher.  Of course, odd numbered revisions can only be obtained by checking out the CVS source and building it so there aren't too many users who have that one ;-)

Comment: gnuplot knows how to do factorials with the `!` operator, you don't need to write your own function for this